# Autofill TextBox connected to ComboBox in VBA Userform

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I am making a userform and because I want to have the contents of my ComboBox wrap to the box, I've connected it to a TextBox as below:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
If Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex > -1 Then Me.TextBox1.Text = Me.ComboBox1.Text
End Sub
```

This works fine. However, I also want the MatchEntry functionality of the ComboBox, so that when I type something into the textbox, it will come up with suggestions for autofill.

Is there any way to do this, or alternatively, any way of making the text wrap in the input of the ComboBox? The latter would be preferable, but looking around, it seems like this isn't possible.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the origin of the combobox data?